# Why are certain seats on public transport a different colour?

Tags: accessibility, transport

On trams and buses, there are often designated priority seats in a special colour for people with special needs. If a person with special needs boards, able-bodied people are supposed to vacate these seats. But doesn't having special seats suggest that able-bodied people don't need to vacate other seats? Wouldn't it be better to have a general rule that able-bodied people should stand if someone else needs the seat?

Comment: I'm confused, what're you asking here?

Comment: this is a very localized question. Most countries I know don't have different color seats, but indications above them. FWIW, in the few cities I have seen different color seats, I found it too violent, even people with real disabilities (specially them!) will feel reluctant to be marked as *disabled* with neon signs, so to speak.

Answer (score 4):

I guess your question is why is there a need for specifically marked seats when normally people give up their seats anyway.

The seats with labels and color are specifically designed for lesser able-bodied people. There's more space to sit and it's close to the entrance/exit. People are required to give up these seats if someone who fits the criteria (pregnant, old, disabled) wants it and they themselves are not part of this group. Every other seat is first come first serve. You're not obligated to give up your seat if a lesser abled-bodied person wants it, but most do because of good manners.

Essentially, the special seating is to somewhat ensure that people don't have to rely on good manners to get a seat if they really need it.

Comment: "that people don't have to rely on good manners" - of course, they still have to, as there is barely a way to enforce giving up the seat if someone doesn't want to (maybe except for the - in my place - somewhat extraordinary event that there is actually any staff of the transportation company around).